# Dynamic SQL and C#.Net

Tags: c#-3.0

I am using Dynamic SQl in my stored Procedure.   In front end I am using C#.net gridview to display the data.

I have three fields in my Table,

1) Active- Bit
2) DateMadeInactive-smallDate
3)Comments-Varchar(Max)

Depending on the condition of the active Value I have to display those three or two fields in the gridview.

If Active= true, Then I have to display active and Comments.

If Active =false, Then I have to DateMadeInactive and Comments Fields.

For Rendering the Active field I am using the following

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Comments" SortExpression="Comments" >
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <%#Eval("Comments")%>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

In my stored Procedure I am checking Like this for null, if its null then I am displaying as false

```
set @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery+  ',isnull(Register.Active,''0'')as Active,
```

Could anybody tell me where do I check for the Active value or Is there any method in SQL which Checks for the True/False condition of the field.

I am not expecting complete answer, just a hint only...

Thank you.

Hari

Answer (score 1):

The [GridView.RowDataBound event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx) is what you're looking for.

When handling the event check the value of the field and show or hide your controls accordingly.

Beware: You **can't** hide the whole column, as it affects every row, you must show or hide the controls inside the column.